# Distribution of P[Y=n] = P[n-1<X<n] for X exponentially distributed

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

From an assignment, we have "Let X be an exponentially distributed random variable with probability density function. $f(x) = λe^{−λx}$, for $x > 0$"

I've worked out that for $P[Y=n] = P[n-1 < X < n] = -e^{-λn}(1+e^λ)$

The second part of the question is "Identify the distribution of Y including the appropriate parameters". It looks kinda exponential, but its missing the λ and has a constant of $(1+e^λ)$ at the front.

I was hoping someone could explain the distribution or point me towards something explaining the specific distribution - I've tried reading about different distributions but I've gotten lost.

Comment: You have not defined $Y$.  Maybe $Y$ is the smallest integer $\ge X$. But do say what it is, else the question is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry, this is the definition of Y: "Suppose we have another random variable Y where IP[Y = n] = IP[n − 1 < X ≤ n] for n = 1, 2, . . .. Obtain an expression for the probability mass function IP[Y = n] of Y ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $Y=n$ if $X\le n$ but $X\gt n-1$.  For $n\ge 1$ this is $\Pr(X\gt n-1)-\Pr(X\gt n)$, which is $e^{-\lambda(n-1)}-e^{-\lambda n}$. That simplifies to 
$$\Pr(Y=n)=e^{-\lambda (n-1)} (1-e^{-\lambda}).\tag{1}$$
If we rewrite $e^{-\lambda(n-1)}$ as $(e^{-\lambda})^{n-1}$, we recognize (1) as the probability mass function of a **geometrically** distributed random variable, with  $Y$  the number of trials until the first "success," where the trials are independent and the probability $p$ of success on any trial is given by $p=1-e^{-\lambda}$.

Alternately, we could without computation reach the same conclusion using the *memorylessness* property of the exponential distribution.